# Save markers in MySQL Maps v3

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have a project of Google maps v3.   I got an example of the internet and changed it. When you click on my map it creates a marker. But I don't know SQL and I need help with the programming of the marker. I tried for 4 hours and didn't have any progress. This is my link for to you see.

You draw your path here->
http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/index.htm

And it loads here -> http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/loady.htm

Use ctrl+u to see the programming.

The part that saves the informations is the `save_waypoints()` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples of how to use MySQL with google maps in the [articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)